# Backup before delete specific rows in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to create procedure which delete some rows with query like:

```
DELETE Car
 WHERE Vin IN (
               SELECT Vin
                 FROM CarDetails
                WHERE Id IN (JH4KA826000000000, ...)
              )
```

But before it will be deleted I would like to have backup of these specific rows.
I will not have access to db to export it manually by sql developer (insert into).
How can I do it by procedure to make it easy to restore if it will be needed?

In my case I don't need the copy of the whole table. Just these deleted rows.

Comment: A delete trigger populating a backup table is probably the best option. That way you don't have to code for every time you need to delete something. Just make sure the trigger is always enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options. If you only want to backup the rows that are deleted by that specific procedure, but don't care if rows are deleted in another way, then I'd just backup the rows in the procedure itself:

```
INSERT INTO car_backup (vin, column1, column2,...) 
  SELECT vin, column1, column2,...
    FROM car
   WHERE Vin IN (SELECT Vin
              FROM CarDetails
              WHERE Id IN (JH4KA826000000000, ...)
              );
DELETE FROM Car
WHERE Vin IN (SELECT Vin
              FROM CarDetails
              WHERE Id IN (JH4KA826000000000, ...)
              )
```

However, if you want to back up every row that is deleted, consider using a `BEFORE DELETE`  trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER car_bd
BEFORE DELETE
   ON car
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO car_backup (vin, column1, column2,...) 
    VALUES (:old.vin, :old.column1, :old.column2,...);
END;

/
```

Another, very clean solution is to use "In-Database Archiving", available since 12.1. That would allow you to set a flag on the row that makes the row invisible. So the row seems deleted to all queries but it remains in the table and can be shown/undeleted if needed.

Pick whatever solution matches your requirements best.

Comment: will the 1st or 2nd solution create new table 'car_backup' on database?

Comment: is it possible to just create a .txt file (by procedure) containing exactly as many 'insert into' as deleted rows? then someone could very quickly and easily restore deleted rows

Comment: The table car_backup as to be created manually

Comment: Sure it is possible to create a text file. But that will be on the server - there are so much more things to maintain then: access to that directory on the server, maintenance of that directory. It's a lot easier to keep everything in the db

Comment: Also with a text file, if the procedure runs several times  you have to go through each individual file to figure out what you want to restore.

Comment: Thanks a lot Koen Lostrie. Could you also show me how to do it by .txt file to just have more alternatives?

Comment: Hmm... sorry I don't have any code ready to do that. As I said, that is a much more complex solution than the options I suggested - both from maintenance side as from development side. There are some client tools (sqldeveloper/sqlcl) that can do this but I don't think there is a built-in api that generates insert statements. In the database world, what you are asking is not a good practice.